# jquery datatables accessing variable in className

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using JQuery Datatable plugin found [here](https://www.datatables.net/). I have the following piece of code. I have a line in my code with the following comment //I need to access the variable row.RECIBO here. In the className parameter below, I am trying to access a variable name so that I can distinguish my class using an ID. How can I accomplish that goal of mine?

```
    var table = $('#tableCLIX1').DataTable({

    "order": [[0, "desc" ]],
    "ajax": {"url": "reciboBackend.php", "type": "POST", "dataSrc": "db" },
    "columnDefs": [{
        "render": function(data, type, row){ return row.RECIBO},
        "targets": 8,
        "className": "tranState" + VARIABLE //I need to access the variable row.RECIBO here
    }],
    "columns": [
    {"data": "RECIBO", className: "recibo"},
    {"data": "NOMCLI"},
    {"data": "CLIENTE"},
    {"data": "FECHA"},
    {"data": "NUMPOL"},
    {"data": "FACTURA"},
    {"data": "TIPO"},
    {"data": "VALOR"},
    {"mRender": function(data, type, full){if(full["TRANSTATE"] == null) return "<button id = 'cancelar" + full["RECIBO"] + full["FACTURA"] + "' class='button-error pure-button cancelar-btn " + full["RECIBO"] + "' > Cancelar </button>"; else return full["TRANSTATE"];}},
    {"mRender": function(data, type, full, meta){return '<a href = "reImprimir.php?recibo=' + full["RECIBO"] + '+&tranState=' + full["TRANSTATE"] + '" target = "_blank"> Imprimir </a>';}}
    ],
    "deferRender": true

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NB: You both have a `columns` `mRender` *and* a `columnDefs` `render` method for column #8, why? There is something wrong with the code.

---

Anyway, `className` is static for all `<td>`'s in the column and does not support callbacks. `render` is strictly about *content* of the cell and cannot be used to add CSS, besides inside elements added as content.

But you can use [**`rowCallback`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) to post process the rendered row, and by that add a class to column #8 using the rows `RECIBO` value :

```js
var table = $('#tableCLIX1').DataTable({
   rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
       $('td:eq(8)', row).addClass('tranState'+data.RECIBO);
   },
   // ...
})
```

Comment: Excellent!!! That is what I needed. For your first comment about render, I will take a look at why I am doing that and then answer. Maybe you might be able to help me to make it cleaner.

Comment: hello David. You seem to have a lot of knowledge with datatables. I am trying to implement lazy loading but not using what is stated here: http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html since I am not doing serverside processing. What are my options? I would like to improve performance